# Android Paint setColor can't parse hex value to int

Tags: java, android

I'm currently trying to take in a hex value for a color, ie `#0000ff` or `#0000ffff` if it's in hexadecimal (if this is right), and then pass it into my Paint object with paintObject.setColor().

However, whenever I try to do something of the following, I always get a failure message saying parseInt() failed with the following inputs:

`String hexColor = "#0000ff";`
`String longerColor = "#0000ffff";`

- `paintObject.setColor(Integer.parseInt(hexColor));`
- `paintObject.setColor(Integer.parseInt(longerColor));`
- `paintObject.setColor(Integer.parseInt("0x" + hexColor.substring(1)));`
- `paintObject.setColor(Integer.parseInt("0x" + longerColor.substring(1)));`

Manually plugging in an integer, ie something like `0xFFFFA500` allows me to just set the color as orange, so I'm pretty confused here. I'm sure its a tiny error that I'm making.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most direct solution would be to use [Color.parseColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#parseColor(java.lang.String)):

```
String hexColor = "#0000ff"; String longerColor = "#0000ffff";

paintObject.setColor(Color.parseColor(hexColor));
```

which accepts the strings you have specified (both rgb and argb).

If the hex strings are not validated for format then be sure to handle the `IllegalArgumentException` thrown by `parseColor`.

---

Alternatively, to follow along your attempts, specify the radix in `Integer.parseInt()`:

```
paintObject.setColor(Integer.parseInt(hexColor.substring(1),16));
```

---

As you have used it, the `Integer.parseInt(s)` assumes a radix of 10 and the only non-digit characters it accepts are a `+` or `-` in the first position.